# TNSPING is working but getting ORA-12514 error in oracle rac

Tags: database, oracle11g

I have created 2 node rac environment on vm.
i am able to do tnsping through scan ip but while connecting i am getting below error:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor

can someone please help?

thanks
rahul

Comment: How re you connecting? Remotely or locally?

Comment: i am using remotely connection